# iOS Simulator cannot load the url

Tags: ios, google-maps

iOS Simulator cannot load **maps.google.co.in**.

I tried to load **‘google maps’** on my iPhone using **safari** browser.But it appeared like the following screens:

[image]

When I touch on **show details** then the following screen appeared

[image]

Please help me how to resolve this issue

Comment: your system's network restricted the **google maps** so you can try with real device and make sure device mobile data is on, don't connect with restricted network.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/maps iphone 11 Pro Max -13.2.2 it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's due to a network restriction, not a Simulator limitation.